# ViewModel nesting and having business logic dependant validation using IValidatableObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Currently I am presenting a payment form, on this payment form it is toggle-able whether to show the [credit card validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code).  Showing the CVV field is dependent on some configuration dependent on some business logic in a few layers down in the app (in my instance some payment gateways do not have / require CVV).

The form is displaying the following fields:

- Card Holder Name
- Card Number
- Card Type (drop-down of Visa, Amex, Master-Card, etc.)
- Expiry Date
- CVV dependent on configuration settings found in database, varies

#### Models (problem with Validate method)

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CardType> CardTypes { get; set; }
    public bool IsCvvEnabled { get; set; }
    public PayProcess { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string CardHolder { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public string Cvv { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // validation of properties CardHolder, Number, Type, etc...

        // how do I read this value?
        if (IsCvvEnabled) 
        {
            int tempCvv;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cvv)) 
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult(Index.CVVRequired, 
                    new[] { "CVV" });
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(Cvv, out tempCvv))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult(Index.CVVInvalid, 
                     new[] { "CVV" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### View

The view looks as follows:

```
<section id="aligned">
    <h3>@ViewRes.Index.Header</h3>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayProcess.CreditCardType)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PayProcess.CreditCardType, 
        "Card Type")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PayProcess.CreditCardType, 
        Model.CreditCardTypes)

    <!-- the other fields ... -->

    @if (Model.PayProcess.IsCvvEnabled)
    {                            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayProcess.Cvv)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PayProcess.Cvv, 
            "Card Verification")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PayProcess.Cvv)
    }
</section>
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var indexViewModel = CreateIndexViewModel(new ProcessViewModel());

    return View(model);
}

private PayIndexViewModel CreateIndexViewModel(ProcessViewModel processViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", CreateIndexViewModel(processViewModel));
    }

    // handle success scenario
}

private IndexViewModel CreateIndexViewModel(ProcessViewModel processViewModel)
{
    var isCvvEnabled = _someDependency.Gateway.SupportsCvv;
    var cardTypes = _someDependency.Gateway.GetSupportedCardTypes
                        .Select(x => new SelectListItem { 
                            Text = x.Name, 
                            Value = x.ID });

    return new IndexViewModel
    {
        CardTypes = cardTypes,
        IsCvvEnabled = isCvvEnabled,
        PayProcess = processViewModel
    };
}
```

#### The Problem

The `ProcessViewModel` contains solely the form input values that the user submits, it does not contain `IsCvvEnabled` as the user is not submitting that value.

How do I correctly perform this validation when the validation needs this contextual information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user isn't submitting the value in the form, then you will have to either manually set it on your post action or you may be able to craft a custom model binder to set the property before it is validated. However for something as trivial as this, I think that is way too much work.

Personally, my preferred way of achieving what you want, is to refactor your validate method to a method that takes in a `ModelState` and then you call this yourself in your post action:

```
viewModel.IsCvvEnabled = _someDependency.Gateway.SupportsCvv;

viewModel.Validate(this.ModelState);

if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

You will have to put the IsCvvEnabled property onto your ProcessViewModel.

Comment: This was my thoughts originally, I'm going to wait a bit to see if someone has any alternatives.  I'll mark this as answered if there's nothing better.